# node js cheerio xml

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I have the below code and it is working fine to get:

```
<troveUrl>http://trove.nla.gov.au/work/23043869</troveUrl>
```

But I would like to get the value after 'id' in the following from the same page and cannot get it!

```
<work id="23043869" url="/work/23043869">
```

here is the code that i currently have

```
var request = require ('request'),
    cheerio = require ('cheerio');
    request('http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=6k6oagt6ott4ohno&zone=book&q-year1-date=2000&l-advformat=Thesis&l-australian=y&q-term2=&q-term3=&q-term0=&q-field1=title%3A&q-type2=all&q-field0=&q-term1=&q-type3=all&q-field3=subject%3A&q-type0=all&q-field2=creator%3A&q-type1=all&l-availability=y%2Ff&q=+date%3A[2000+TO+2014]&q-year2-date=2014&n=1', function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('troveurl').each(function(i, element){
          var id = $(this);
          console.log(id.text());
        });
      }
    });
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(element.attr('id'));` work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should pass `xmlMode: true` in the options object, then you can parse it as XML.

You can then grab the tag and data with `$('tag').attr('attribute')` and `$('tag').text()` to get the data between the tags as you've done.

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
request('http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=6k6oagt6ott4ohno&zone=book&q-year1-date=2000&l-advformat=Thesis&l-australian=y&q-term2=&q-term3=&q-term0=&q-field1=title%3A&q-type2=all&q-field0=&q-term1=&q-type3=all&q-field3=subject%3A&q-type0=all&q-field2=creator%3A&q-type1=all&l-availability=y%2Ff&q=+date%3A[2000+TO+2014]&q-year2-date=2014&n=1', function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html, {
          xmlMode: true
        });
        console.log($('work').attr('id'))
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1222447 next time you can track it by searching for expected comments or expected terms in the source codes (not in the full text questions offered by Google). e.g. hunting the term ```xml``` in the cheerio code base https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/search?q=xml&type=Code shows that there is some ```xmlMode``` variable influencing the behavior. It is not enough alone, but I guess it is what Ben used either this time or some time ago

Comment: If you pass `xmlMode: true` to the code, the code should still work.

Comment: [`xmlMode`](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/CheerioOptions/#xmlMode) is now [`xml`](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/CheerioOptions/#xml)

Answer (score -1):

The real issue lies in the syntax you used to get the value after 'id'. The following code will not console.log the id out.

```
var id = $(this);
console.log(id.text());
```

The correct syntax should be `$('your element').attr('id')` like is mentioned in Ben Fortune's answer above. However, passing `xmlMode: true` in the options object is not a necessity. 
Passing `xmlMode: false` in the options will also work if you are using the correct syntax.