# Why Cheerio XML parsing with Crawlee doesn't return text() for *some* keys?

Tags: python, javascript, xml, parsing, cheerio

Considering an `XML` file like [this one](https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=test&hl=fr&gl=FR&ceid=FR:fr) (Google New RSS feed) and `item` like this:

```
<item>
  <title>Test Like a Dragon Ishin...</title>
  <link>https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMie2....</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">CBMie2h0dHB...</guid>
  <pubDate>Fri, 17 Feb 2023 15:00:03 GMT</pubDate>
  <description>Test Like a Dragon Ishin...</description>
  <source url="https://www.jeuxvideo.com">jeuxvideo.com</source>
</item>
```

I try to learn `Cheerio` (via `Crawlee`) and wrote the following (quite-working) function:

```
const crawler = new CheerioCrawler({
    async requestHandler({ request, response, body, contentType, $ }) {
      $("item").each(function (i, ref) {
        const el = $(ref);
        const title = el.find("title").text();
        const link = el.find('link').text();
        const published_on = el.find('pubdate').text();
        const published_by = $("source").text();
        const snippet = el.find("description").text();

        console.log("TITLE: ", title);
        console.log("LINK: ", link);                 // DOESN'T WORK
        console.log("PUBLISHED_ON: ", published_on);
        console.log("PUBLISHED_BY: ", published_by); // DOESN'T WORK
        console.log("SNIPPET: ", snippet )
        console.log("AUTHOR: ", author);
      });
    },
  });
```

It might be obvious (except for me), but I do not understand why I can't retrieve `link` and `published_by` content whereas it's working for the other ones.

Any clue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you making the `$` variable? Did you pass `{xml: true}` as an option to Cheerio? I'm not familiar with Crawlee, but maybe it's building `$` for you, so maybe test it on a plain XML string with `$` first, then figure out how to adjust Crawlee options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node js cheerio xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012652/node-js-cheerio-xml)

Comment: The reason why you are not able to retrieve the link and published_by content is that you are using incorrect selector strings for these elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in CheerioCrawler.
The error is due to the fact that option `xmlMode: true` is not set in `DomHandler` & `WritableStream` interface to process the streaming XML input.

See my response [Crawlee Issue #1794, to Why CheerioCrawler parsing doesn't return text() for *some* XML keys?](https://github.com/apify/crawlee/discussions/1794)

Comment: Indeed! Waiting for the fix! 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Passing [`{xml: true}`](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/CheerioOptions/#xml) as a Cheerio option works:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<item>
  <title>Test Like a Dragon Ishin...</title>
  <link>https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMie2....</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">CBMie2h0dHB...</guid>
  <pubDate>Fri, 17 Feb 2023 15:00:03 GMT</pubDate>
  <description>Test Like a Dragon Ishin...</description>
  <source url="https://www.jeuxvideo.com">jeuxvideo.com</source>
</item>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xml: true});
const items = [...$("item")].map(e => {
  const text = s => $(e).find(s).text().trim();
  return {
    title: text("title"),
    link: text("link"),
    publishedOn: text("pubDate"),
    publishedBy: text("source"),
    snippet: text("description"),
    guid: text("guid"),
    url: $(e).find("source").attr("url"),
    isPermaLink: $(e).find("guid").attr("isPermaLink"),
  };
});
console.log(items);
```

I'm not familiar with Crawlee, and scanning the docs doesn't show an obvious way to add this option to `$`. Presumably, you can use `$ = cheerio.load(body, {xml: true})` inside the handler though.

Note also that I'm using `pubDate` rather than `pubdate` since XML is case-sensitive, while HTML isn't.

By the way, `console.log($.html())` is a good way to debug this sort of problem; it shows what Cheerio parsed the text to.